# How to restart failed spring batch csv insert into mysql?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have simple project for csv file processing into mysql. My question is which is the intelligent way to handle recovery of failed inserts.
For example in a file of 100 rows i have inserted 10 then  vm crashes and when i restart the app it will insert again all rows, but i wat to start from 11. I’m processing file in chunks.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are following a Spring Batch project similar to https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/, then you can follow the various rules around job *[restartability](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html#restartability)*.  The Spring Batch will track the progress of your job (e.g. how many chunks have been committed), so in the case of failure you may resume from where it left off.

In a little more details, the Spring Batch [Meta-data Tables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html) keep track of the details for your job, including a *commit_count* in each Step.  These details are persisted into your database when completed, so the data about your job will available when you restart even following disaster recovery.

Comment: I second this answer. In the example of the question, if the chunk size = 10, then restarting the job will resume from record 11, not from the beginning.